# Модальное окно в map() react js

Tags: reactjs

помогите, пожалуйста. я не понимаю как мне открывать модальное окно, с элементами.
Есть массив, который генерит в компоненте разное количество элементов (от 4х и до 10) и для каждого должно быть модальное окно просмтотра. 
я через map() создаю нужное количество элементов и далее...

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import Modal from "react-modal";

 class General extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        modalIsOpen: false
    };
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
}

openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
}


closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
}

render() {

    return(
        <div className="general">
            {this.props.filteredBooks.map((item, index) =>
            <div className="book-item" key={index}>
                <div className="size-bg" onClick={this.openModal}>
                    <img src={item.Image}/>
                </div>
                <h3>{item.Name}</h3>
                <p>{item.Author}</p>
                <div className="rating" key={index}>
                    <img src={item.ImageRating} />
                </div>
            </div>
            )}
            <Modal
                isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                ariaHideApp={false}
                className="Modal-book"
                overlayClassName="Overlay-book"
            >
                <div className="image-modal">
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Закрыть модальное окно</button>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}


}
```

export default General;

все работает как надо, но изображение там постоянно одно, а мне надо как то его менять в зависимости от нажимаемый элемент

Comment: `this.openModal` покажите

Comment: полностью компонент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сохранять `src` картинки для модального окна в `state`

```
<div className="size-bg" onClick={() => this.openModal(item.ImageRating)}>
```

Тогда `openModal` будет таким

```
openModal(modalSrc) {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true, modalSrc});
}
```

И вставлять в модальный компонент `<img src={this.state.modalSrc} />`

Comment: Супер.все работает как надо, вы волшебник:) а можно еще один вопрос, как мне получать этим жк способом и остальные части карточки? Такие как автор название и рейтинг